# How to add date range in invoice search view and print the selected range in the report?

Tags: search, report, odoo, date-range, invoice

I added two fields for date range in account.invoice, it works fine but i am not able to print the dates in report. Here is my code:

> 'date_from':fields.function(lambda *a,k:{}, method=True,
>   type='date',string="Date from"), 'date_to':fields.function(lambda
>   *a,k:{}, method=True, type='date',string="Date to"),

```
<field name="date_from" filter_domain="[('date_invoice','&gt;=',self)]"/>
<field name="date_to" filter_domain="[('date_invoice','&lt;=',self)]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your rml report 
For a date_from
[[date_format(object.date_from)]] 
and For a date_to
[[date_format(object.date_to)]]